# is there something wrong with this git ignore file

Tags: git, ignore

I don't know what it is but my git ignore does not always work. I did `git rm --cached` on the files, but that still are being reported as untracked by git status. It seems that when I change it it will stop working. I was wondering if anyone can spot an overt syntax error I am making that I can not see.

Specifically right now the file `assets/styles/compile` is not being ignore after adding the line `assets/scripts/main-built.js` to the file

```
WebWorkbench.mswwsettings
packages.config
.DS_Store
.sass-cache
*.sublime-workspace
*.sublime-project
_sgbak/
.sass-cache/
assets/video/
*.mp4
*.ogv
*.wmv
*.webm
*.mov
nbproject/project.properties
nbproject/project.xml
nbproject/private/private.xml
assets/styles/.nodemonignore
assets/styles/style.css
assets/styles/compile
assets/scripts/main-built.js
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Check if there are any whitespaces at the end of the lines:

```
assets/styles/compile
```

And maybe a `git status` before and after you edit the `.gitignore` file would help.

Comment: your me hero, i would have missed that forever